# Grouping hover text of multiple line with different mode in plotly R

Tags: python, r, plotly

Plotly has the feature of showing hover text of multiple lines simultaneously. For example:

```
dt <- data.table(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10), z = rnorm(10)+2)
plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "lines") %>% 
    add_trace(x = dt$x, y = dt$y, name = "curve 1", mode = "lines") %>% 
    add_trace(y = dt$z, name = "curve 2", mode = "lines")
```

However, if their modes are different, the hover text won't be grouped. For example:

```
dt <- data.table(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10), z = rnorm(10)+2) 
plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "lines") %>%
    add_trace(x = dt$x, y = dt$y, name = "curve 1", mode = "lines+markers") %>% 
    add_trace(y = dt$z, name = "curve 2", mode = "lines")
```

plotly in python has a way to do it ([Line Plot Modes](https://plot.ly/python/line-charts/))
I couldn't find the solution to plotly in R.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the raw JSON of the example provided in the link you can see that `hovermode` is set to `x` (the default is `all`).

If you set `hovermode` to `x` in `layout` in `R` you should get the desired output as well.

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

set.seed(42)

dt <- data.table(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10), z = rnorm(10)+2) 
plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "lines") %>% 
  add_trace(y = dt$y, name = "curve 1", mode = "lines+markers") %>% 
  add_trace(y = dt$z, name = "curve 2", mode = "lines") %>% 
  layout(hovermode = 'x')
```

[image]